# Using playlist playback in VLC

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, playback

### BACKGROUND

I'm using VLC to listen to an audio book on win10, which have hundred .mp3. So, I put all of the .mp3 file into a playlist in VLC. Obviously, I can not have enough time to play all of files at one time. **When I have time to listen to audios playlist, I want to start with the last position I quit.**

### QUESTION

I already open auto playback for videos and audios, but I did not work with my playlist. I find a solution to create a custom bookmark for my playlist(playback > custom bookmarks > manage), which can jump to last postion I left handly. I am wondering is there any solution can help me automatically start from the last position I left?

Comment: Have you tried going the preferences, then setting "Continue playback" to `Allways`?

Comment: Yes，that will enable video and audio auto playback instead of playlist

Comment: On my side, playlist resumes from where i left off using that settings.